# bouncycastle 1.49 has no crl generator for X509v3

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am quite new to java programming. I want to create a basic crl but I have realised that X509v3  has no crlgenerator. I would like to know how the crl is generated for X509v3. so far this what I have got.
http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Certificate+Revocation+Lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RFC5280 x509v3 certificates are to be combined with x509v2 CRL-s

In plain english: As of today (March 2014) x509v2 is the latest version of CRL and it's OK to use it with x509v3 certificates. You should use the `X509V2CRLGenerator` in your application.

See also:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509